# Js one string, one id / discord v12

Tags: javascript, discord

I would like the bot to record one ID in one line and when I enter the command "banallid" it blocks all IDs.

The bot enters the ID in the .JSON file after the decimal point

```
const Members2 = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => Date.now() - member.user.createdAt < 1000*60*60*24*10).map(member => member.user.id);
const data = JSON.stringify(Members2, null, 4);
// write file to disk
fs.writeFileSync('./warns.json', data, 'utf8');
console.log(`Zapisane pomyślnie!`); 
}
```

And ban command/msg:

```
 if (message.content.startsWith("banallid")) {
    message.channel.send("Total: "+memberCount+" \n"+Members2+"");
   console.log(Members2) 
    guild.members.ban(Members2)
```

And my problem is:

```
 (node:21592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [BAN_RESOLVE_ID]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to ban.
```

What is wrong? :/